# Get recipe ingredients in paragraph from unstructured data

Tags: javascript, recipe

I'm a beginner in js and I'm trying to use js code to fetch ingredients from a website like this, [justanotherrecipeblog.tumblr.com](https://justanotherrecipeblog.tumblr.com), that doesnt structure data or use any special name or class for each subtopic?

This is the code I came up with:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".caption > p");
var re = new RegExp(" [ 0-9]");
if (elems){
   ing = re.test(elems);
} 
 document.write(ing);
```

The code only give values like true, false and undefined and it doesn't ingredients. Please help.

Comment: `.test` only says if it matches or not, not getting the matches

Comment: @Daniel A. White. Okay thanks, how can I get the matches?